# Symfony monolog fingers crossed handler not excluding specified http codes

Tags: symfony, logging, symfony4, monolog

I am using the fingers crossed handler to buffer log messages until an error occurs. Below is my config:

```
monolog:
  handlers:
    buffer:
      action_level: error
      excluded_http_codes: [401, 403, 404]
      handler: logger
      type: fingers_crossed
    logger:
      formatter: monolog.formatter.json
      include_stacktraces: true
      level: info
      path: php://stderr
      type: stream
```

I am finding that exceptions that should match the `excluded_http_codes` are still being output into my log.

I have dug into the `Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\FingersCrossed\HttpCodeActivationStrategy` class and am finding that `$this->requestStack->getMasterRequest()` is returning `null` by the time the exception reaches the `isHandlerActivated` method.

Is there something I am clearly doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is resolved since updating my composer packages. I'm not sure which package was specifically responsible

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible your errors are occuring in a different handler? If I'm not mistaken you only block a couple errors in your buffer handler and none in your logger handler

Comment: The two handlers shown are the only active ones. The `logger` handler records all errors that are level `info` and above, but the `buffer` handler is wrapped around the `logger` handler and will only flush the messages in `logger` when an `error` or higher occurs. I know the handler is triggered by the exception, but for some reasons a sub request seems to be created to handle the exception